# significance on ggplot boxplots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value, ggpubr

I'm trying to denote statistical significance on my boxplot (ggplot in R) but I am only seeing "no significance" even though I suspect at least "paring-rind" and "prime" are significantly different.

I have my data as `div.sh` (`dput()` below) and I specify statistical comparisons in `sh.comparisions`, then plug that into a `ggplot` dohicky, shown below:

```
library(ggpubr)

sh.comparisons <- list(c("control","paring-rind"),c("control","prime"),
                       c("paring-rind","prime"))

p.sh <- ggplot(data=div.sh,
               aes(x=type, y=diversity.otu_ord..index....shannon..)) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.25) +
  stat_compare_means(label.y=2.8) +
  stat_compare_means(label="p.signif",ref.group = ".all.",
                     hide.ns = TRUE,comparisons = sh.comparisons) 
print(p.sh)
```

Which gives me this image: [image]
Now, like, I understand completely if these are the true comparisons and I'm not looking to massage any data.  However.  It's stupid hot in my office right now and I'm feeling burnt out--I'm certain at the very least "paring-rind" and "prime" are significantly different.  Thanks!!

```
> dput(div.sh)
structure(list(sample = c("X1_S1_L001", "X2_S2_L001", "X3_S3_L001", 
"X4_S4_L001", "X5_S5_L001", "X6_S6_L001", "X7_S7_L001", "X8_S8_L001", 
"C_S9_L001"), diversity.otu_ord..index....shannon.. = c(2.08927604225762, 
1.69169533050154, 2.49826489705959, 1.48216768128529, 2.35449296228345, 
2.21297785313827, 2.47390723729832, 1.91649702459675, 1.86244750738137
), sample.id = structure(1:9, .Label = c("1_S1_L001", "2_S2_L001", 
"3_S3_L001", "4_S4_L001", "5_S5_L001", "6_S6_L001", "7_S7_L001", 
"8_S8_L001", "C_S9_L001"), class = "factor"), core = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("1FB-4", "5FB-2", 
"5FB-3", "6FB-3", "control"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("control", "paring-rind", 
"prime"), class = "factor"), dna.cocn = c(0.05, 0.06, NA, NA, 
0.04, 0.03, NA, NA, NA), raw.reads = c(123669L, 74952L, 104254L, 
100385L, 111822L, 106772L, 95535L, 101397L, 85591L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
9L))
```

Comment: i get the same pvalues. you are comparing n=1 vs n=4 and n=4

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by that? Ah wait, I got it.  Thank you for your patience!